# Limit access to EC2 based on Resource tag IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to limit access to a EC2 instances for a group if the instance has a tag of "protected=true"

I've used [this AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/) as a guide but I'm not able to get there.

Here is the relevant policy:

```
{
        "Sid": "Stmt23578h8eh48r483h8r",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1513797341000",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/protected": "true"
            }
        },
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "58484htjg8rjf89438u8",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DeleteTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

To em this should allow everything (which is good) and *then* deny everything if the ResourceTag match occurs.  And according to the docs, I need to limit tags to keep a user for taking over a resource.

This however is not working. The group is able to see the instance.

Comment: Where are you assigning these policies? Just to non-Admin users?

Comment: Assigning to a group which will have elevated privileges, but not quite admin. Restricting certain instances, billing, and a couple of buckets.

This is a small deployment so I'm not opposed to doing some legwork - I don't have 500 users or anything

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restrict view access based on tags, kindly refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888942/aws-iam-show-only-untagged-ec2-instances/47894430#47894430).

Comment: Ok, if I'm reading your answer and the docs correct I could still limit the groups ability to terminate an instance though, correct? While it'd be nice to limit visibility, actually stopping an instance is far more dangerous for us

Comment: Yes, because TerminateInstances and StopInstances support the  "ec2:ResourceTag/tag-key" condition, but I don't follow the reason of the down-vote. The original ask/concern in the question was the user can all instances even though the shared policy has been applied, which is explained by the answer because the describe APIs do not support the condition key, the condition does not take effect in "Sid": "Stmt1513797341000". With the above policy is the user able to stop or terminate an instance with the specific tag?

Comment: Looks like the down-vote was reversed